# Using strings.xml items on a listview array

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm coding an Android app with android studio.
I'm displaying a ListView who gets its content from a String Array. I want to use the strings.xml items in the array of the listview, but I can't. Please help me.
I'm doing this for the first item of the array:

```
 public final String palanca= (getResources().getString(R.string.palanca));
private String [] formls = {palanca,"@string/uMR","@string/new1","@string/new2","@string/new3"};
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a string array resource in your strings.xml.

```
<string-array name="colors">
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
</string-array>
```

Use your string array from your Java just like you would any other string resource.

```
private String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);
```